# calculating an average and comparison in python

Tags: python, compare, average

I have a set of values tgat represent the number of people in a postcodd on average. These are `pcode1 = 239`, `pcode2 = 245`, `pcode3 = 210` and `pcode4 = 217` now comes the bit where I am stuck. I have assumed that the average is `allpcode = 220`.

Is there a way to write a code in python such that I can compare each individual pcode to the total average? What I want to do exactly is say compare `pcode1` to `allpcode` and if `pcode1` is higher/lower than `allpcode` display the average from `pcode1` and say that `pcode1` is lower than `allpcode` or higher than `allpcode`. I'd then like to repeat for all other pcodes :)

Id like to display on screen all the averages that are lower and all averages that are higher.

So something like pcode 3 and 4 averages are lower than all pcode average and pcode 1 and 2 are higher than all p code.

Is it possible to create such a code because i have no idea how/where to start?

Comment: Your question title says "calculating an average". You can calculate the average of your values with `(pcode1+pcode2+pcode3+pcode4)/4`—or, better, if you put them into a `dict` as in my answer, `sum(pcodes.values()) / len(pcodes)`. But you're going to get 227.75, not the 220 that you've assumed.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, where you frequently want to iterate over all of a set of values, it's generally better to use a single `list`, `dict`, or other collection variable, instead of a bunch of separate variables. For example:

```
pcodes = {1: 239, 2: 245, 3: 210, 4: 217}
```

Now you can write code like this:

```
pcodes = {1: 239, 2: 245, 3: 210, 4: 217}
allpcode = 220

for pcode, value in pcodes.items():
    if value < allpcode:
        print('code {} is lower than allpcode'.format(pcode))
    elif value > allpcode:
        print('code {} is higher than allpcode'.format(pcode))
```

---

If you *really* want to have separate variables, you have to do more work, like this:

```
pcode1 = 239
pcode2 = 245
pcode3 = 210
pcode4 = 217
allpcode = 220

for i, value in enumerate((pcode1, pcode2, pcode3, pcode4)):
    if value < allpcode:
        print('code {} is lower than allpcode'.format(i + 1))
    elif value > allpcode:
        print('code {} is higher than allpcode'.format(i + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list if you only want to match values:

```
>>> pcode1 = 239
>>> pcode2 = 245
>>> pcode3 = 210
>>> pcode4 = 217
>>> lis = [pcode1, pcode2, pcode3, pcode4]
>>> allpcode= 220

>>> for i,x in enumerate(lis):
    if x < allpcode:
        print "pcode{} is less than {}".format(i+1,allpcode)
    elif x > allpcode:    
        print "pcode{} is greater than {}".format(i+1,allpcode)
...         
pcode1 is greater than 220
pcode2 is greater than 220
pcode3 is less than 220
pcode4 is less than 220
```

Better use dictionary:

As variables are just references to values in python so you can't
access a variable name. And in case you've lots of `pcodes` then defining a variable for each of them is bad way to solve this problem, using a dict is going to be much cleaner.

```
#create dictionary with keys named pcode1, pcode2,...     
>>> dic = {'pcode1':239, 'pcode2':245, 'pcode3':210, 'pcode4':217}

>>> for k,v in dic.items():
    if v < allpcode:
        print "{} is less than {}".format(k ,'allpcode')
    elif v > allpcode:    
        print "{} is greater than {}".format(k,'allpcode')
...         
pcode3 is less than allpcode
pcode2 is greater than allpcode
pcode1 is greater than allpcode
pcode4 is less than allpcode
```

Though dictionaries don't maintain any order, you may have to `collections.OrderedDict` or `sorted` here to get keys in a particular order.